# How do I get mouse movements work properly for several different ImageIcons inside a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am currently trying to write my first very simple image manipulation program with Swing. It is supposed to be possible to browse for and add images as ImageIcons and move around these images on the screen. The photos should be layered on top of each other as they are added, and clicking an image should remove it.

The program runs but I am having the following functionality problems.

This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

class Image {
    private int x = 80;
    private int y = 80;
    private String filepath;
    private ImageIcon image;

    public Image(int x, int y, String filepath){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.filepath = filepath;
        image = new ImageIcon(filepath);
    }

    public Image(String filepath){
        this.filepath = filepath;
        image = new ImageIcon(filepath);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(image.getImage(), x, y, null);

    }

    public void undraw (Graphics g, Color c ){
        g.setColor(c);
        g.fillRect(x,y,image.getIconWidth(), image.getIconHeight());

    }

    public boolean containsXY (int x, int y){

        if ( this.x <= x && this.y <= y){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void move (Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        undraw(g, Color.WHITE);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        draw(g);
    }

}


class PaintSurface extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    private int x, y;
    private JButton browse;
    private Collection <Image> images = new ArrayList<Image>();
    private final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    private Image selected;

    public PaintSurface(JButton b){
        browse = b;
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        browse.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPG & GIF", "jpg", "gif");
                fc.setFileFilter(filter);
                fc.showOpenDialog(browse);
                buttonPressed(fc);

            }
        });
    }

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        for (Image i: images){
            i.draw(g);

        }

    }

    public void addImage(Image i){
        images.add(i);

        Graphics g = getGraphics();
        i.draw(g);

    }


    public void buttonPressed(JFileChooser fc){
        File selectedFile = fc.getSelectedFile();

        Image i = new Image(x, y, selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());

        addImage(i);
        repaint();
    }

    public Image findImage(int x, int y){
        for (Image i: images){
            if (i.containsXY(this.x, this.y)){
                return i;

            }

        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean removeImage (Image i){

        Graphics g = getGraphics();
        i.undraw(g, Color.WHITE);

        return images.remove(i);
    }

    public void moveImage (Image i, int x, int y) { //

        i.move(getGraphics(), x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();

        Image i = findImage(x, y);

        if (i != null) {
            removeImage(i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();

        selected = findImage(x,y);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();

        if (selected != null) {
            moveImage(selected,x,y);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

    }
}


class GUI extends JFrame {

    public GUI(){
        super("ImageApp");

        JLabel instruction = new JLabel("Clicking anywhere on the screen will set the location for the next added image.");
        JButton browse = new JButton("Add image");
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new PaintSurface(browse);
        panel1.setLayout(null);
        panel2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        instruction.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        getContentPane().add("North", instruction );
        getContentPane().add("South", browse);


        add(panel1);
        add(panel2);
        setBounds(300,0,800,800);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);

    }

}

public class PhotoApp extends GUI {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        GUI PhotoApplication = new GUI();

    }
}
```

These are the problems:

- When I have added several images, the mousefunctionality suddenly stops to work and I can't move any of the images. They get "stuck" somehow.
- When I have added several images, I can only control (move) the latest added one.
- When clicking to remove an image, it is removed even though I don't click inside the image but close to the image. It isn't removed if I click far away from the image (so it's sort of working). It is only supposed to be removed if clicking inside the image!
- When clicking to add an image, if I press "Cancel" I get a bunch of errors
- The pictures are supposed to be layered on top of each other, but when I move an image around now it "erases" the older images.

Can anyone help? I would be so thankful because I have been stuck a long time with this.

Comment: You don't need to list out the same problems twice.

Comment: In your buttonPressed() method, you create a new Image, passing x and y. What are their values? you never set them

Comment: @FredK but I do set them, to x and y, which is set to values of the latest mouseclick in the mouseClicked method?

Comment: @OfeliavanAnalhard Do you know you can accept answers which solves your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I have outlined the problematic code for some of your questions.

> When I have added several images, I can only control (move) the latest added one.

You are only returning one: `public Image findImage(int x, int y)`. And:

> When clicking to remove an image, it is removed even though I don't click inside the image but close to the image. It isn't removed if I click far away from the image (so it's sort of working). It is only supposed to be removed if clicking inside the image!

Your `containsXY()` seems to be messed up here: `if ( this.x <= x && this.y <= y)`. Hint: a 1 pixel square image with x = 0 and y = 0 does not contain x = 50, y = 50. This causes part of the first issue I addressed.

> When clicking to add an image, if I press "Cancel" I get a bunch of errors

It will not return a File if you do not select one:
`File selectedFile = fc.getSelectedFile();`

> The pictures are supposed to be layered on top of each other, but when I move an image around now it "erases" the older images.

You are `undraw`ing it with WHITE: 
`g.fillRect(x,y,image.getIconWidth(), image.getIconHeight());`